# Extracting the index from index.html into a string

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string:

```
file = "index.html"
```

And I want to convert it into a string like this:

```
"index"
```

I went about it like so:

```
file.split(".")[0..-2].join(".")
```

What would be a better way?

Comment: You're  close: `file.split('.').first`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways would be to use a regular expression:

```
file[/.+(?=\.)/]
  #=> "index"
```

or the method [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-index):

```
file[0, file.index('.')]
  #=> "index"
```

In the first method, `(?=\.)` is a *positive lookahead* that matches a period which is not part of the match of the regular expression.

Another way would be to convert the unwanted part of the string to an empty string, but I don't believe that reads as well:

```
file.gsub(/\..+/, '')
  #=> "index"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'pathname'
path = Pathname.new('index.html')
path.basename('.*').to_s  # => "index"
```

C-;

Comment: I gave you a much higher grade.

Answer (score 0):

There are of course a million different ways to do this, but based on your question I like this:

```
'index.html'.gsub(/\.html$/, '')
```

Edit: or `‘index.html’.tr('.html’, ‘’)`